# Linux: passing commands to CLI using a script

Tags: linux, bash, automation, command-line

is there any way I can pass commands to the CLI of a tool directly?

I would like to script some actions, for example:

```
./OpenBTS < "tmsis"
```

I do not need to retrieve the results (I watch it in the log file). Do
you have any idea how I could realize that?
There is now way to do this using command line parameters, at least not that I found out. So it looks like I have to figure out sth myself. Any idea? Maybe I could automate screen in a way to detect the prompt and "paste" my command there. Are there tools for this on Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: wow! Exactly! Big thanks. very nice tool, good to knwow it now =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with a heredoc, something like:

```
./OpenBTS <<EOF
tmsis
EOF
```

as in the following transcript, which feeds input into `sed`:

```
pax$ sed 's/^/Q/' <<EOF
> hello
> goodbye
> EOF
Qhello
Qgoodbye
```

Alternatively, you can just echo stuff directly into it, like

```
echo "tmsis" | ./OpenBTS
```

as per the following example:

```
pax$ echo 'hello
goodbye' | sed 's/^/Q/'
Qhello
Qgoodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to do this, but if the tool listens on stdin then you can use a heredoc for this.

```
./sometool << EOF
action1
action2
quit
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It is not working in this case but that's not related to the command. Will use it for sure later. Thx for telling me that trick :)